# Covariant derivative of a vanishing tensor component

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Is the covariant derivative of a vanishing tensor component necessarily zero?

Comment: Yes or no questions don't work well here.  Do you have more to ask?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. A vanishing-tensor component or a vanishing component of a tensor? In the first case yes it is zero. In the second case the covariant derivative is not of a component. What you probably mean is if the component of the covariant derivative of the tensor. For example if the 11 component of rank 2 tensor is zero then is it true that the 11 component of the covariant derivative will also be zero. The answer is no, not always.

Comment: also, by vanishing, do you mean identically zero or do you mean zero at some spacetime coordinate? If the former, then it is what MBN said. If the latter then it need not be zero ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat ill-defined. This answer is based on what I gather the OP is asking.

No. *Generically*, the covariant derivative of a tensor is zero only if the entire tensor is zero. Note how the covariant derivative is defined (taking example of a 1-form)
$$
(\nabla_\mu A)_\nu = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu} A_\lambda
$$
Now, suppose a paerticular component of the 1-form identically vanished, say $A_0$. We then find
$$
(\nabla_\mu A)_0 =  - \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu 0} A_\lambda \neq 0
$$